# v-for and v-if causing issues with an undefined variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my Vue application, I have a very small line of code based on a v-for loop and it works until I throw a V-IF into it.

THe following works:

```
<div v-for="date in dates" :key="date">
  <th v-for="store in stores">@{{store.stock}}</th>
</div>
```

However, when I try to get it to only show that value if the date in the object matches the dates object, I get that `store` is undefined

```
<div v-for="date in dates" :key="date">
  <div v-for="store in stores">
  <th v-if="store.date === date">@{{store.stock}}</th>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here are my objects:

```
stores: [
  {
    store: "123",
    date: "2021-09-01",
    stock: "145"
  }
]

dates: [
  {
    date: "2021-09-01"
  }

]
```

Why am I having such an issue when trying to match the dates in the v-if?

Comment: `store: "123,` is missing closing `"`

Comment: Is `th` in a `<table>`?

Comment: No Such issue exist, please find thisa fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dpe2wza8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of use v-if with v-for you can use computed to get store you need display and then use just one v-for

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div
      v-for="store in activeStore"
      :key="store.stock"
    >
      {{ store.date }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default ({
  data() {
    return {
      count: 1110,
      stores: [{
        store: 'test',
        date: '2021-09-01',
        stock: '145'
      }, {
        store: 'test',
        date: '2021-09-02',
        stock: '146'
      }, {
        store: 'test',
        date: '2021-09-03',
        stock: '147'
      }, {
        store: 'test',
        date: '2021-09-04',
        stock: '148'
      }],
      dates: ['2021-09-01', '2021-09-02', '2021-09-03', '2021-09-00']
    }
  },
  computed: {
    activeStore: function() {
      return this.stores.filter((store) => {
        if (this.dates.includes(store.date)) {
          return store
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a little mistake. `date` should be `date.date`!

```
<div v-for="date in dates" :key="date">
  <div v-for="store in stores">
  <th v-if="store.date === date.date">@{{store.stock}}</th>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using **computed** property

```
<div v-for="date in dates" :key="date">
  <div v-for="(store, indexer) in getFilteredStores(date)" :key="indexer">
  <th>@{{store.stock}}</th>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in your computed, define the below handler to get the store for particular dates

```
computed: {
 getFilteredStores() {
   return targetDate => { // targetDate is the argument passed to the handler
    return this.stores.filter(store => store.date === targetDate);
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

vue discourages the use of **v-if** inside a **v-for**

it is much better to use a **computed property** that filters the list and in the
**v-for** you pass the already filtered list

Comment: That is _not_ true. VueJS discourages using `v-if` and `v-for` **together**: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-with-v-for. There is no recommendation for/against nesting `v-if` inside `v-for`

Comment: https://learnvue.co/2020/02/6-techniques-to-write-better-vuejs-v-for-loops/#3.%20Avoid%20use%20v-if%20in%20loops you just need to search ‍♀️

Comment: The article you say rehashes what I've said: using `v-if` **with** `v-for`. It never mentions not using `v-if` **inside** `v-for`. You just need to learn how to read ‍♀️

Comment: This doesnot points to the issue that user faces

Comment: We are not supposed to use v-if and v-for together! But at the same time I wanted to confirm that this is not the case for the code that's mentioned in the question becoz in the qsn the v-if and v-for are used in two separate statements